# How to frame and install new windows in balloon frame with T1-11 siding?

Tags: windows, framing, sill

Remodeling the 1930s wood-framed building we live in, and ready to make new openings to install new windows. It's difficult to describe how the walls are so I made a diagram below.

[image: unusual wall windows]

Basically, from outside to inside: T1-11 siding nailed to OSB, nailed over original clapboard and tar paper, nailed to original balloon framing, which is gusseted to a newer 2x4 interior wall that was added at some point.

There is essentially no overhang from the roof at all, so the new windows will get a lot of water. I've purchased a few new construction windows, which have nailing flanges. Assuming I can make these work, but not sure. After internal framing, I'm considering:

1. Cut rough opening
2. Cutting back just the T1-11 back to make room to nail the flanges directly to the OSB (which will be backed by new framing where needed)
3. Apply flashing/flex tape to sill
4. Coerce/wedge a drip cap wedged under the T1-11 at the top.
5. Install, nail up and caulk the window
6. Trim to make it nice.

Considering another approach, but not sure. Might be easier because I could install the windows from the inside. After internal framing:

1. Cut rough opening, with room as needed for new exterior sill and jambs
2. Install new exterior sill, jambs, and drip cap, to waterproof the opening; aluminum or similar
3. Install some form of molding/stop to then take the window from the inside, after removing nailing flanges
4. Put the window in, make it nice, caulk and foam, etc

SO- Will either approach work? Or is there a door number 3 I should be thinking about?

Comment: Remodel windows without a flange are quite common and may be much easier it is basically your #2 option but you would need to frame them in.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Well done for your first question! While you're waiting for an answer, browse through the [help] to learn how to make the most of the site. Also, wouldn't that be "window number 3"? :)